# Having issue in setting JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME in .bash_profile - Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I am using Amazon linux in EC2 instance.  I am trying to add JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME in .bash_profile file but when i echo $JAVA_HOME nothing is getting displayed. I have attached .bash_profile and mvn screenshot. Please help in resolving this issue.

[image]

Comment: check is the .bash_profile file for user `root` or `ec2-user` if the profile file is for `ec2-user` then it wont be available for root user

Comment: Thanks @karthikeyan for revert. bash_profile has Java home and m2 home variables in both places/home/ec2_user as well as in /root

Comment: Only JAVA_HOME is needed and put the bin directory into the PATH nothing else is needed....

Comment: You didn't export the JAVA_HOME, M2, M2_HOME

Comment: Thx for the revert. Now i have added
`# User specific environment and startup programs

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.48.amzn1.x86_64
export JAVA_HOME
M2_HOME=/opt/maven
M2=/opt/maven/bin
export M2_HOME
export M2
PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$M2:$M2_HOME:$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
`   But it is still not showing up.